# How can I avoid dntypes.ExcelErrorName()

Tags: datanitro

In my spreadsheet I have cells that contain a string such as

```
=some string here
```

Excel displays this cell as below if formatting as general. This makes sense because Excel is trying to calculate a cell with a function that doesn't exist

```
#Name
```

DataNitro returns the cell value as (which also make sense)

```
dntypes.ExcelErrorName()
```

I can manually specify the cell as text, which Excel subsequently then displays the string, and DataNitro returns the string. However this is unfeasible for the amount of cells I would need to this.

Even if I try and skip over these cells I can't check the type like I can with most other classes

```
type("a") == str
True
```

but checking against dntypes.ExcelErrorName returns

```
dntypes is not defined
```

How can I either replace these cells with some other value, or format them as plaintext?

**Edit**

Wrote a function to handle these values for the time but I would rather only use this as a temporary fix

```
def errorfix(row):
for i,value in enumerate(row):
    if type(value).__name__ == "ExcelErrorName":
        row[i] = "EXCEL NAME ERROR"
return row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the values through this function:

```
def get_text(val):
    if not isinstance(val, ExcelError):
        return val

    if type(val) == ExcelErrorDiv0:
        return "#DIV/0!"

    if type(val) == ExcelErrorNA:
        return "#N/A"

    if type(val) == ExcelErrorName:
        return "#NAME?"

    if type(val) == ExcelErrorNull:
        return "#NULL!"

    if type(val) == ExcelErrorNum:
        return "#NUM!"

    if type(val) == ExcelErrorRef:
        return "#REF!"

if type(val) == ExcelErrorValue:
    return "#VALUE!"

raise TypeError("Unknown Excel Error")
```

`isinstance(val, ExcelError)` is the best way to check if something is an error.
If you're doing this a lot, you may want to make a subclass of `Cell` that does this whenever you call value.